Who are the mutants on the "Wanted" poster in X-Men '97?
In X-Men '97 (Season 1, Episode 4: "Motendo / Lifedeath - Part 1"), Jubilee and Roberto (Sunspot) find themselves transported into a world reminiscent of a 90s beat-em-up video game. In the background, a pixelated "Wanted" poster depicts a number of characters, presumably all mutants.
While I can recognize Cyclops, Gambit, Scarlet Witch, and Wolverine, I'm not sure about the identities of the others.
Screenshot of the "Wanted" poster:

Can anyone identify these unknown mutants from the "Wanted" poster?

It seems to be based on X-Men #141's cover from Days of Future Past.

Characters in that poster.
Top Left - Bottom Right

Cyclops
Colossus
Storm
Nightcrawler
Angel
Iceman
Beast
Sprite
Magneto (Gambit in '97 poster?)
Quicksilver
Jean Grey (Scarlet Witch in '97 poster?)
Wolverine
Forge? (Professor X in '97 poster?)
Polaris
Havok
Banshee


Fairly certain #11 is the Scarlet Witch

Possibly but more logically it would be Jean.

Jean died in X-Men #137. The headgear the character is wearing belongs to the Scarlet Witch. Additionally, #13 is likely Professor X as Forge wasn't introduced until X-Men #184.

If you check the poster the wording of #13 certainly appears to be Forge.

Several of those seem to be changed up in the X-Men '97 poster. #11: This character's headgear features a red color scheme and shape more reminiscent of Scarlet Witch than Jean Grey. #13: This figure appears bald and lacks the long black hair associated with Forge. This suggests this might be Professor X rather than Forge. #9: This character's design leans closer to Gambit than Magneto. The absence of a red helmet and chestplate, along with red eyes, a black cowl, and a brown coat collar, all point towards it being Gambit.

There are some obvious thematic sequencings: Row (1) are highlights from the "all-new, all-different" x-men era (Claremont 1975 on). Row (2) has most of the original x-men. Row (3) has the family members in order Magneto, Quicksilver, Scarlet Witch. The last column tends to be leftovers that don't fit in elsewhere.

Noted and comments added to answer. Thank you all. ☺
